# Are there sources for potential wave solutions for which the electromagnetic far-field is zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, antennas

Are there sources for electromagnetic potential propagating wave solutions for $\phi$ and $\overrightarrow{A}$

for which the electromagnetic far-field $\,>\!\lambda\,$ in vacuum is zero $\overrightarrow{E}=\overrightarrow{B}=0\,$ globally in open space?

So that
$$ 0=\overrightarrow{E}=-\nabla\phi-\partial_{t}\overrightarrow{A}$$
and
$$0=\overrightarrow{B}=\nabla\times\overrightarrow{A}$$

Comment: My former [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/495317/where-does-the-energy-go-to-for-a-charged-sphere-with-pulsing-radius) did lead somehow to this equation.

Comment: Standing wave in an empty box made of perfectly conducting walls has zero field outside the box. Sources in that case are in the walls of the box.

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks I have to update my question I mean propagating waves

Comment: There can be propagating wave in the box as well, only it won't propagate indefinitely, it will reflect off the walls and bounce inside the box.